# Excel cell format - #/# - converts to data automatically

Tags: excel, cell

I am putting together a list of data and some of that data is in the following format

('#/#' - # single digit numeral. Example 1/1 however excel automatically interprets it as 1/1/2020. I have tried researching customer excel cell formats:
?"/"? or 0"/"0

None seem to work excel returns the following 
4383/1

Any ideas on how can I format the cells to recognize #/# without converting the text?

Comment: If you want to enter `1/1` then it will need to be text. Format the column as text.

Comment: Excel thinks that it's way smarter than we are and that any value formatted as a date is a date.  Working in the wood products industry (lots of fractions and lengths that can interpreted as dates), we deal with this all the time and the only way around it to use strings.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I have tried the following: highlighting column then 'format cells' then selecting Text - however that just converts the data to whole number. If the format is changed on an empty column and then data is copied - the copied data still retains the date format - 1/1/2020

Comment: try `# ??/??` format

Comment: You will need to format the cell before entering the data.